# ANgular - use service in route resolve after it was loaded by ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I want to use a service in `state resolve` which is loaded by `ocLazyLoad` also in `state resolve`. Like below:

```
.state('meniu', {
            url: '/meniu',
            params: { lang: 'ro'},
            templateUrl: 'views/meniu/meniu.html',
            controller: 'meniuController',
            resolve:{
                      loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                 return $ocLazyLoad.load(['pageNavPropsService', 'meniuCtrl', 'customHeader', 'customFooter']);

                       }],
                       ,
                       loadMyData: ['$http','$stateParams', 'GetDataService', function($http, $stateParams, GetDataService){
                           var path = '_global/views/services/json/' + $stateParams.lang + '_data.json';
                           return  GetDataService.getData(path);
                       }]

            }
        })
```

I've tried sth like this but with no success:

```
loadResources: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                 return $ocLazyLoad.load(['getDataService','pageNavPropsService', 'bauturiCtrl','customHeader', 'customFooter'])
                                                    .then( function(GetDataService){
                                                        GetDataService.getData("path");
                                                    });
                       }]/*,
```

How can this be done?